# Abort keystroke sequence?

Tags: vim, command, key, abort

When using Vim I sometimes find myself midway through entering a key combination and change my mind or realise it's incorrect (I'm still learning).

For example I may have typed <kbd>d</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd> and be about to press <kbd>d</kbd> in order to delete 4 lines and realise this is not what I want to do. How can I abort the current sequence of keystrokes?

Comment: +1 because I didn't know you could display keyboard key icons in a post on SO!

Comment: To the close voter, how is **VIM** off-topic?

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel: How is this programming related?

Comment: @Felix: there's a thread on Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su

Comment: @Felix See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su I won't get into the debate any further, as I'm a VIM "fan" ;)

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes, @Ivo Wetzel: Ok, you guys win ;) I also love VIM, the question was just not *programming-related* enough for me. But anyway... no hard feelings :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

*(no more text)*

Comment: Good old Esc. It's funny how such a commonly used key requires you to leave the home row in an editor that is all about avoiding that.

Comment: @Martinho Personally I have escape bound to my caps-lock key. That really made Vim alot smoother to use.

Comment: @Abuh Unfortunately that doesn't work on all systems :( But depending on your keyboard layout there might be keys which are useless to programming anyways, such as `§`, which is Shift+3 on a German keyboard perfect place to put ESC on :)

Comment: @Abuh: same thing here. My pinky does all my Esc-ing :) It's just annoying that I keep toggling Caps Lock when I'm using someone else's machine :(

Comment: @Martinho the keyboard that vi was originally developed on had escape where tab is now: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KB_Terminal_ADM3A.svg

Comment: @Randy: I never understood the why of Esc. That explains it. Thanks for that! And that fulfills my quota of random trivia learned for today.

Comment: @Matt Joiner: Just tried it and it seems so... however, on a German keyboard, this is a pain to type ;)

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel, @Martinho Fernandes, @Randy Morris: Use `Ctrl+[` instead of `Esc`. @Felix Kling: Does this mean that `Ctrl+[` also works for aborting?

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> also aborts the current command.

Comment: Can you explain why? What instruction does Ctrl+C perform?

Comment: @Matt Joiner : See `:help CTRL-C`. It explicitly says :`In Normal mode, any pending command is aborted.`

Comment: @Matt Joiner It is a common shortcut in unix enviroments: `C-c` in terminal sends signal INTERRUPT (SIGINT) which should interrupt currently running process. Vim just inherited this behavior and applied it to currently running command.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer <kbd>CTRL+[</kbd> over escape at all times, including aborting the current command. It's quicker and easier to type, particularly if you remap caps lock to ctrl.